# Пропуск повторов элементов последовательности

Tags: c#, .net, linq

Есть ли в LINQ предложение или метод, который бы не выводил повторы элементов последовательности. Например, для последовательности `1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 4, 1, 5, 1, 6` предложение или метод должен определить, что `1` повторяется несколько раз, и выбрать его один раз.

*Main.cs*:

```
using System;
//добавить ссылку
using System.Linq;

class Program {
    public static int Main() {
        //источник данных
        int[] ara = new int[] { 1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 4, 1, 5, 1, 6 };
        //создание запроса
        var query = 
                from val in ara
                //???
                select val;
        //выполнение запроса
        foreach (var i in ara) {
            Console.Write("{0} ", i);
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.ReadKey();
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Результат должен быть таким: `1 2 3 4 5 6`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Просто вызвать `Distinct()`. Ну или извратиться с группировкой :D

http://ideone.com/9xN5RX

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

public class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        int[] a = new int[] {1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 4, 1, 5, 1, 6};
        var b = from x in a group x by x into t select t.Key;
        var c = a.Distinct();
        Console.WriteLine(String.Join(" ", b));
        Console.WriteLine(String.Join(" ", c));
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо Вам Qwertiy!